# Ubuntu 12.02 to 14.04, Wordpress tries to use wrong MySQL user on single post pages

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache-2.4, lamp

I just ran an update to Ubuntu 14.04 on my web server. It went super smooth and I thought all was well, but I just noticed the inner most pages of my Wordpress site throw an unusual error.

```
Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

The username 'www-data' is only the linux username for apache, which is not anywhere in the website code. And all the upgrade commands were run as root as well. I am at a loss why MySQL is trying to use this user on single post pages when it is provided my correct Wordpress MySQL user by PHP and works for every other page correctly.

The biggest updates were the Ubuntu core and Apache from 2.2 to 2.4. I found this post which sounds like a similar issue, but also has no answer. ([nagios mysql check using unexpected user after upgrading from ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04](https://serverfault.com/questions/649871/nagios-mysql-check-using-unexpected-user-after-upgrading-from-ubuntu-12-04-to-14))

Any help/thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Where did this message come from? Where is the rest of the message?

Comment: It renders on the page. It is all that renders minus a couple HTML tags. It happens when Wordpress tries to query the database for the first time on a single post page it looks like.

Comment: It was my friend, he had used mysql_connect in a custom theme. Which messed up MySQL and caused this error.